# How to add border-radius to ion-img in Ionic 4

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I need to add `border-radius` to `ion-img` but it seems `shadow DOM` won't let me modify.

**HTML**

```
<ion-img [src]="img-url" [alt]="alt"></ion-img>
```

**CSS**

```
ion-img  {
    border-radius: 10px !important;
}
```

Comment: `<ion-img></ion-img>` have some issues. try with simple html `img` tag.
e.g: `<img [src]="yourImgPath" style="border-radius: 10px;">`

Comment: This will work, but I need `<ion-img>` tag for lazily load an image.

Answer (score 27):

The correct, non-obvious, way to do this is with [CSS shadow parts](https://ionicframework.com/blog/customize-your-ionic-framework-app-with-css-shadow-parts/).

In this case [ion-img has a shadow part `image`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/img#css-shadow-parts) so our SCSS looks like:

```
ion-img::part(image) {
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Yes, the part has no quotes and is the full word "image" (not "img" we need the part name, not the target tag name).

Comment: I did not recognize, that the shadow part can work with image that way. Thank you. If I set the class of image to `your-img` can this system still work? Or will it apply to all images on the page?

Comment: @Nasenbaer I'm not sure I understand your query. The only class name here is `ion-img`. The shadow part names are configure and controlled by the Ionic Team. You might be able to affect the specificity of adding another class to the particular ion-img tag but I've not played with that as Angular view encapsulation means you can isolate this quite a lot already.

Comment: can you be that kind and add the frontend html code to your sample? without `class=your-img` its not easy to get the exact point.

Comment: The necessary HTML is in the OP's question. I'm not sure why you want to add additional classes.

Comment: Just to prevent to add very similar question to stackoverflow. Lets leave it. Thank you

Answer (score 14):

**HTML**

```
<ion-img [src]="img-url" class="your-img"></ion-img>
```

**CSS**

```
.your-img {
    border-radius: 10px !important;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. put the image inside of card

```
    <ion-card>
        <ion-img  src="imag"></ion-img>                      
    </ion-card>
```

2. after that set the style of the image
3. set image with and heigth to 100% in `ion-img` style
4. modify the value of radius in the ion-card component

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
<ion-avatar>
   <ion-img [src]="item.image"></ion-img>
</ion-avatar>`
```

```
ion-avatar {
    --border-radius: 10px;
}
```

I find this solution in
[image: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/10558]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<ion-img>` inside `<ion-thumbnail>` and styling works great.
HTML:

```
 <ion-thumbnail slot="start">
      <ion-img src='/assets/avatar-images/defaultuser.png'"></ion-img>
    </ion-thumbnail>
```

CSS:

```
ion-thumbnail {
          --border-radius: 10px;
          border: 1px solid var(--grayColor);
          
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

It's tricky to [encapsulate style with Shadow DOM](https://css-tricks.com/encapsulating-style-and-structure-with-shadow-dom/#article-header-id-4), but there are ways.

In this case, does it work for you with an inline style attribute?

```
<ion-img [src]="img-url" [alt]="alt" [style]="border-radius: 10px;"></ion-img>
```

Otherwise you might try adding a `<style></style>` tag to the inner HTML of the Shadow DOM with the border radius.

A modified example from the attached link:

```js
const host = document.getElementById('shadow-host');

host.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
<style>
  img {
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
</style>
`
```

Comment: Tried the code, but it doesn't work. I changed the title and added Ionic 4