# How to add border-radius to img inside <ion-img>?

Tags: ionic-framework, sass, ionic4, shadow-dom, ionic5

I want to set a [border-radius](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp) to the `img` tag inside `<ion-img>`.

I've tried to add

```
img { border-radius: 16px}
```

in `.scss` component style, in `variable.scss`  and in `global.scss` but did not work.

Comment: Maybe its been overridden by another class, can u ry with !important
So like this `img {border-radius: 16px !important;}`

Answer (score 2):

[Try to add](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59665906/5059916) your CSS class to `<ion-img>`.

**HTML** - home.page.html

```
<ion-img [src]="img" class="your-class"></ion-img>
```

**CSS** - home.page.scss

```
.your-class {
   border-radius: 16px !important;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

[image]