# make border radius of ionic image in ionic react app

Tags: css, reactjs, ionic-framework

I am making an ionic react app. I can not make border radius of ionic image. Help me to solve the problem.
Here is my code of js file:

```
import { IonGrid, IonImg } from '@ionic/react'; 
import './aboutUs.scss'; 

const AboutUs = () => {
return (
        <IonGrid className="about-us">
            <IonImg className="about-image" src="https://cutt.ly/MWaU9I0"></IonImg>
        </IonGrid> 
       );
     };

export default AboutUs;
```

Here is my code of scss file:

```
.about-us{
padding: 1.25em;
  .about-image{
    border-radius: 5em;
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add border-radius to ion-img in Ionic 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58640790/how-to-add-border-radius-to-ion-img-in-ionic-4)

Answer (score 0):

You most likely want to set it to important, to override ionic defaults, and hide overflow, i.e:

```
.about-us{
  padding: 1.25em;
  .about-image{
    border-radius: 5em !important;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

According to this duplicate here:

[How to add border-radius to ion-img in Ionic 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58640790/how-to-add-border-radius-to-ion-img-in-ionic-4)